# Unix Skipping first line if empty

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a script running that will take as input a text file, then take the last column after skipping the first 12 lines, then output them in another text file.

```
for (( r=1; r<5; r++));
do
  awk 'NR>12' IMSI$r.txt | awk '{print $NF "\r"}' > N$x
  awk 'NR>12' IMSI$r.txt | awk '{print $NF "\r"}' >> out
  x=$(($x+1))
done
```

My problem is that sometimes, the first line in the file is empty and I'll have to skip it.

So the code will become something like

```
for (( r=1; r<5; r++));
    do
      %If (line1  is empty) then delete line and overwrite the new file
      awk 'NR>12' IMSI$r.txt | awk '{print $NF "\r"}' > N$x
      awk 'NR>12' IMSI$r.txt | awk '{print $NF "\r"}' >> out
      x=$(($x+1))
    done
```

I tried :

```
if [ ${line:-null} = null ]; 
then awk 'NR>1'
```

Is this correct ?
And how can I overwrite it on IMSI$r.txt , without getting an empty file ?

Thanks for the help guys.

EDIT:

An example as requested:

text1.txt:

```
1 xxx 123
2 yyy 123
3 zzz 123
```

so the output will be

```
123
123
123
```

text2.txt:

```
"empty line"
1 xxx 123
2 xxx 123
3 xxx 123
```

output:

```
123
123
123
```

As you can see, both files will provide the same output, while they have different structures ( the second one has an empty line at start)

My code won't work because it will skip every time 12 lines, and I can't know if I have to skip 12 or 13, because sometimes the first line is empty. So i have to add an IF statement, to skip the first line if it is empty.

Hope that is enough info

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example where there's a case that the first line is empty? It's confusing too what you meant about `I'll have to skip it`. Do you mean you wouldn't process it at all and don't do anything with `N$x` and `out`? You're saying you'd get an empty file. How is it possible when only the first line is empty?

Comment: What about if the first two lines are blank ?

Comment: @Jidder the two lines are always blank together ? or a combination of 0 -1 -2 blank lines ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this `awk` instead:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { I = NF ? 12 : 13 } NR > I' "IMSI$r.txt"
```

And you can simplify your two awks as one:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { I = NF ? 12 : 13 } NR > I { print $NF "\r" }' "IMSI$r.txt"
```

You can also just specify `ORS` instead of using `"\r"`:

```
awk -v OFS='\r\n' 'NR == 1 { I = NF ? 12 : 13 } NR > I { print $NF }' "IMSI$r.txt"
```

Lastly to make things more efficient, use `tee` instead of calling `awk` twice:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { I = NF ? 12 : 13 } NR > I { print $NF "\r" }' "IMSI$r.txt" | tee -a out > "N$x"
```

P.S. Always place your variables around `""` to prevent word splitting and any possible pathname expansion.

#### Update

If file is in DOS format, you'd need to specify a different RS:

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' ...
```

Or remove `\r` at the beginning of every line:

```
awk ... '{ sub(/\r/, "") } ...
```

Checking number of fields with `NF` for validating if a file is empty or not may be enough but you can be strict with checking real blank lines (no other spaces) too:

```
NR == 1 { I = /^$/ ? 13 : 12 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need is a variable (`c` below) that only gets incremented/tested when you have fields:

```
for (( r=1; r<5; r++));
do
  awk -v OFS='\r\n' 'NF && ++c>12{print $NF}' "IMSI$r.txt" | tee "N$x" >> out
  x=$(($x+1))
done
```